# Python, pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we have a 100 rows pandas Dataframe "frame", then we define a method

```
def test(a_dataframe):
  a_dataframe["new_col"] = "new_value"
  a_dataframe = a_dataframe.iloc[0:10,:]
```

if we run test(frame), the frame object would have the "new_col", but still have 100 rows.

Could anybody explain why the method test could add new column to a Dataframe but couldn't subset it?

Thanks

I thought the "test" method would add new column to a Dataframe as well as subset it with the first 10 rows.

Comment: @SomeDude what do you mean by "python's methods takes a copy of the parameter you send"? The function gets passed the original df and does modify it (adds a new column), it's just that `iloc` returns a new df so it doesn't have any effect on the original and reassigning it within the function just creates a new local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the function with `test(frame)`, the local variable `a_dataframe` inside the function will initially contain a reference to the `frame` object that exists outside of the function. Now the two lines within the body of the function do very different things:

1. `a_dataframe["new_col"] = "new_value"` does *not* change the value of the local variable `a_dataframe`. Instead, it invokes the `__setitem__` method on the dataframe that is referenced by that variable. So the `frame` outside the function is changed accordingly.
2. `a_dataframe = a_dataframe.iloc[0:10,:]` *does* change the value of the local variable `a_dataframe`. This has nothing to do with the `iloc` method. It is simply because with `a_dataframe = <anything>`, you assign a new value to the local variable `a_dataframe`, thus overwriting the reference to `frame` it initially contained.

If you do want to drop rows from `frame` from within the function, you could use something like `a_dataframe.drop(range(10, 100), inplace=True)`. This would work similarly to case 1. above, calling a method on the dataframe that is referenced by the local variable. Note that the first argument of the `drop` method refers to index values, which are not necessarily identical to the row numbers that `iloc` refers to.